# Problem with Piecewise constraint in Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am facing a problem in my model with piecewise constraints that is making my one of the decision variables equal to zero for every value.

My objective function is:

```
\begin{equation}
    \min \sum_{t=1}^T p_{t} \cdot (1+r) \cdot y_{t}    
\end{equation}
```

where `p` is the price, `y` is the quantity (decision variable) and `r` is the price surcharge. `t` is the index for time periods.

and my constraints are:

```
\begin{equation}
    M q_t > \sum_{i=0}^N \beta_{i} X_{it} - p_t (1+r) \quad \forall t=1,\dotsc,T
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    -M (1-q_t) \leq \sum_{i=0}^N \beta_{i} X_{it} - p_t (1+r)\quad  \forall t=1,\dotsc,T
\end{equation}
```

The problem is that the value of `r` depends on which interval the value of `y` (decision variable) lies as shown by the following piecewise function:

```
\begin{equation}
    r_t (Y_t) = 
    \begin{cases}
        % s_0
        0 & \mathrm{if }\; Y_t \leq b_0 \\
        % s_1
        0.05 & \mathrm{if }\; b_0 < Y_t \leq b_1 \\
        % s_2
        0.1 & \mathrm{if }\; b_1 < Y_t \leq b_2\\[6pt]
        ... & \mathrm{if }\; ...
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

where `b_0, b_1` etc. are set of quantity intervals = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]

I have written piecewise constraints in Gurobi (Python) as:

```
for t in range(1, T + 1):
    m.addGenConstrPWL(quantity[t], r,
        [0, 50, 50, 100, 100, 150, 150, 200, 200, 250], 
        [0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2]
    )
    m.addConstr(-M * (1 - q[t]) <= gp.quicksum(beta[i] * X[i, t]
        for i in range(N + 1)) - p[t] * (1+r),
        name = "price threshold 1"
    )


for t in range(1, T + 1):
    m.addGenConstrPWL(quantity[t], r,
        [0, 50, 50, 100, 100, 150, 150, 200, 200, 250],
        [0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2]
    )
    m.addConstr(M * q[t]) >= gp.quicksum(beta[i] * X[i, t]
        for i in range(N + 1)) - p[t] * (1+r),
        name = "price threshold 2"
    )
```

where `M` is big M, `q[t]` is binary variable, `X[i,t]` is a given/known value, `beta` is a binary variable and `r` also a binary variable.
There are also some other constraints but the problem is with these constraints.
Although the model optimizes the program it makes all the values of `beta` variable equal to zero which shouldn't be the case.

Could anyone please guide me where I am making mistake, whether in writing piecewise constraint or some other thing?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not fit here and has already been posted on OR StackExchange: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7089/problem-with-piecewise-constraint-in-gurobi

Comment: @salidi - It might have been considered a programming problem had you posted a complete program.